# R contour3d gives "subscript out of bounds" for one function but not another that returns identical values

Tags: r, contour

Using the example from [here](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/misc3d/html/contour3d.html)...

```
#this works fine
f <- function(x, y, z) x^2+y^2+z^2

#but I want to try it with vectors it fails
vec_dot <- function(a, b) sum(a*t(b))
f <- function(x, y, z) vec_dot(c(x,y,z), c(x,y,z))

#check some values each function returns
for(y in 1:10) {print(f(y/10,0,0))}

#draw the isosurface
d <- seq(-2, 2, len=20)
contour3d(f,Tc,d,d,d,engine="standard")
```

When I run this I get:

```
Error in tris[3 * (1:n) - 2, ] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: contour3d ... contourTriangles -> makeTriangles -> unzipTriangleMatrix
```

But commenting out the second `f` works, giving me a sphere. Both functions `f` give the exact same values, as far as I can tell. Is there some hidden number-type-that-fails-with-contour3d that `sum()` returns but `print()`s exactly the same as a regular number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functions `vec_dot` and `f` do not vectorize well. The `contour3d` function passes in a vector of `x`, `y`, and `z` values and only calls the `f` function once.

So rather than calling something like

```
for(y in 1:10) {print( f(y/10,0,0) )}
```

R typically passes in all the values it wants a once

```
print( f(1:10/10,0,0) )
```

which, as you can see, only returns one value. You can use the `Vectorize` helper function to "fix" your function

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x, y, z) vec_dot(c(x,y,z), c(x,y,z)))
```

but the original definition

```
f <- function(x, y, z) x^2+y^2+z^2
```

it likely to be far more efficient.

Comment: so what would be a better way of implementing `vec_dot` in a way that handles a vector of vectors?

Comment: Well, curve3d would never pass along a list of vectors. So if you want your function to work with curve3d that's kind of moot point. The `sum()` function always collapse vectors to a single value; you always need an explicit `Vectorize()` or `sapply()` to more carefully control collapsing.